# Does the order of natural joins matter

Tags: sql

If I say:

```
A NATURALJOIN B
```

Is that the same as:

```
B NATURALJOIN A
```

Similarly, if I say:

```
A NATURALJOIN B NATURALJOIN C
```

How is that supposed to be evaluated?

Comment: Order shouldn't matter.  See the wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join

Comment: Order affects the order of columns returned (if you do `SELECT *` instead of specifying them).

Comment: @Thilo I'm sorry I don't follow, I'm a complete beginner at SQL. Would you be able to show me an example with tables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are my remarks:

1. *NATURALJOIN* is two words: `NATURAL JOIN`
2. The order of the tables makes no difference. Exception: when you `SELECT *`, then the list of selected columns is all columns of the first table, then all columns of the second table.
3. Don't use `NATURAL JOIN`s. It joins tables by their common columns. If the tables happen to share a column name like "text", "description" or "name" this will be used. Imagine you write a program with a `SELECT` statement, where two tables person and job are joined by person_id. Later you add a column "description" to both tables. Suddenly your program will fail completely to get any matching record, because "person_id" may match, but "description" won't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. unfortunately, I have to learn natural joins because it's part of the course I'm doing. I understand the first part of my question but what about the second part? How would I evaluate 3 natural joins. I assume you natural join a to b, then the result of that joined to c?

Comment: Yes, just as you mentioned yourself: SELECT ... FROM A NATURAL JOIN B NATURAL JOIN C. You first join A and B. Then with that result set you join C. But the order does not matter, because in the end all column names common to two tables or more will have been regarded. Let's say there is A(a,x,y) and B(b,y,z) and C(c,x,z), at last you will only get result rows where Ax=Cx and Ay=By and Bz=Cz, whatever order you use. Example: Order A, B, C -> 1. Join A and B by Ay=By to get AB. 2. Join C with AB by Cx=ABx and Cz=ABz. Um, well, I hope my way of explaining is not too confusing.

Comment: Yeah I understand that thanks, but just out of curiosity, what if A and B didn't have any common attributes, so then you would be NATURAL JOINing an empty set with C? Which will just give you C?

Comment: You would cross join the tables, i.e. get a cartesian product, because every record "matches", as there is no criteria that would speak against it. With five records in A and three in B you'd get 15 records which you would then join with C.